# Como usar .htaccess com 2 argumentos

Tags: htaccess

Procurei na internet, achei alguns exemplos, porem não entendi muito bem, por exemplo, eu preciso que quando seja acessado `site.com/stream/nome` ele execute o arquivo `stream.php`, porem dentro do arquivo `stream.php` eu consiga pegar o valor `nome`, como posso fazer isso ??

Answer (score 1):

Seria isto:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^stream/([^/]+)$ stream.php?nome=$1 [L,QSA]
```

- A flag `L` impede que os próximos *RewriteRules* sejam executados se o *match* for acessado
- A flag `QSA` faz passar as variáveis da *querystring*
- O `RewriteCond` com `!-f` verifica se é arquivo não existe
- O `!-d` verifica se a pasta existe
- O `$1` pega o valor de dentro dos parenteses em `([^/]+)`

Nota que se stream.php estiver em uma sub-pasta (como [mostrado aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/202926/3635)) deve usar:

```
RewriteRule ^stream/([^/]+)$ pages/stream.php?nome=$1 [L,QSA]
```

No caso se houver mais de um PHP, conforme o desenho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([^/]+)$ pages/($1).php?nome=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Pergunta: se nenhum caminho for passado na URL, o que acontece? Seria exibido o `index.php` no root normalmente? Ou uma vez definido uma regra de reescrita ele deixa de considerar o `index.php`, isto é, se a URL não casar com nenhuma definida, o servidor tenta acessar a página normalmente?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sim, por isto usei o `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`, no caso nenhum caminho passado tenta inicialmente acessar o `index.php`. Mesmo que index.php não exista na pasta não vai redirecionar no caso acima, porque é necessário 2 "matches", algo como: `site.com/matchA/matchB`

Comment: Entendi. Sempre achei que se eu definisse uma regra, eu precisaroa definir para todos os casos, como fiz na minha resposta com `^$` para caso não fosse informado o caminho. Isso facilita muito as coisas xD

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss é mais no regex que no mod_rewrite, se o regex "casa" tudo e não há nada definido no rewritecond ou atende todos requisitos deles, então passa e o `[L]` impedirá outros `rewriterules`, se não houver a flag `[L]` duas regras podem se misturar e se atrapalhar, claro que tem hora que é desejável misturar.

Answer (score 0):

Apenas completando a resposta do Guilherme.

Caso seja necessário redirecionar outras URL, você pode fazer algo como:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Remove qualquer possível / no final da URL:
RewriteRule   ^(.*)/$   /$1 [L,QSA]

# Casa as URL /stream/foo para /pages/stream.php?a=foo:
RewriteRule   ^stream\/(.*)$   /pages/stream.php?a=$1  [L,QSA]

# Casa as URL /foo para /pages/foo.php:
RewriteRule   ^(.+)$   /pages/$1.php [L,QSA]

# Casa a URL / para /pages/index.php:
RewriteRule   ^$   /pages/index.php
```

Assim, os seguintes redirecionamentos ocorrem:

```
site.com/             =>  site.com
site.com              =>  /pages/index.php
site.com/foo/         =>  site.com/foo
site.com/foo          =>  /pages/foo.php
site.com/foo/bar      =>  /pages/foo/bar.php
site.com/stream/      =>  site.com/stream
site.com/stream       =>  /pages/stream.php
site.com/stream/foo/  =>  site.com/stream/foo
site.com/stream/foo   =>  /pages/stream.php?a=foo
```

---

<sub>Esta resposta completa a outra [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/202926/5878) do usuário, que é praticamente a mesma que esta, porém, se alterado o enunciado desta, a resposta do Guilherme pode perder o sentido.</sub>

Comment: Usei exatamente da forma que você mostrou, apenas alterando `RewriteRule   ^$   /pages/index.php` para `RewriteRule   ^$   index.php` por que a index.php está na raiz, quando eu coloco qualquer um desses dois `RewriteRule   ^stream\/(.*)$   /pages/stream.php?a=$1  [L,QSA]` ou `RewriteRule   ^(.*)/$   /$1 [L,QSA]`, qualquer URL começa a retornar erro 500.

Comment: Olhando o log retorna o erro `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.`

Comment: De fato não está 100%. A ideia é essa, mas a execução não exatamente. Estou tentando achar onde errei.

Comment: Tudo bem, qualquer coisa estou aqui, estou fazendo testes também.